# how to remove Neo4j nodes with duplicate properties?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j 2.1.6, I have nodes that are non-unique in respect of a certain property, `inputID`.

Using Cypher, how do I remove all nodes that are duplicates in terms of a given property, leaving only uniques?

I have tried the following...

```
MATCH (n:Input)
WITH n.inputID, collect(n) AS nodes
WHERE size(nodes) > 1
FOREACH (n in tail(nodes) | DELETE n)
```

...but it results in...

```
Expression in WITH must be aliased (use AS) (line 2, column 6)
"WITH n.inputID, collect(n) AS nodes"
      ^
```

Thanks,

G

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're not aliasing that `WITH` variable.  Change this:

```
WITH n.inputID, collect(n) AS nodes
```

To this:

```
WITH n.inputID AS inputID, collect(n) AS nodes
```

Answer (score 4):

As you correctly found out, using tail on a collection will let you remove the duplicates, don't forget to remove relationships before the node (DETACH) and alias the field as FrobberOfBits mentioned:

```
MATCH (n:Input)
WITH n.inputID AS inputID, collect(n) AS nodes
WHERE size(nodes) > 1
FOREACH (n in tail(nodes) | DETACH DELETE n)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16455407)

Comment: Yes, I wanted to comment on FrobberOfBits answer to add the "DETACH" bit, but I can't comment due to reputation, I did put that as a note, but some "Liam" removed my note.